# Switch statement not working

Tags: iphone

Switch statement is not working. Using switch statement to update the views ater timer is invalidated. In switch statement it is supposed to switch views from first to second view but it is not doing so.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger viewControl; 

@synthesize viewControl;


 -(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

  if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

 [audioPlayer pause];

 [timer invalidate];

  } else {

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [audioPlayer play];

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11 target:self selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];     
  }  

}

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
switch(viewControl)
{

 case 0:
 [self performSelector:@selector(FirstViewController) withObject:nil];

 break;

 case 1:

 [self performSelector:@selector(secondViewController) withObject:nil];

 break;  

 case 2:  

 [self performSelector:@selector(thirdViewController) withObject:nil];

 break;
}          
}

-(void)FirstViewController {
FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[viewController release];

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(secondViewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)secondViewController {
SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

[secondController release];

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(ThirdviewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

Any ideas what is missing in the code.

Comment: I don't see any reference to `viewControl` except for in the switch statement. What is that value and where does it come from?

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's easier to read.

Comment: You might consider adding a log statement inside displayviewsAction to show what "viewControl" is set to. I suspect it is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

The switch is over a variable named "viewControl" that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in the code. You are going to have to give us more information to make a proper answer possible.

Answer (score 1):

Switch statements like your are meant for integer values (hence case:1,2,3,etc.).  You are not even passing anything to the method when the timer invalidates, so you could use a switch with class names, random data, etc. and it would still never work.  Use BOOLean values instead.

Comment: i have never used switch statement before so if you can tell me where exactly i m wrong and how i can fix it.

Comment: A switch statement is just a sort of multi-branched if statement. Each "case" corresponds to a value of the variable being branched on.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `default:` case to your switch statement that logs the value that you're switching on, like this:

```
switch (viewControl) {
    case 0: {
        //...
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        //...
        break;
    }
    default: {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh! The value I'm switching on isn't what I expect! viewControl == %d", viewControl);
        break;
    }
}
```

That won't fix your problem, but it'll help you figure out what's going on.